# Defining pie chart slice colors with Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm trying to create specific colors for certain values/slices, but can't find much documentation on it. I know it's possible for bar charts and such, even pie charts in Javascript, and one of their examples has a colors option, but modifying it does nothing for me.

This is what I have:

```
pie_chart = {
             'data': 
                     [
                     {     'labels': ['V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9'],
                           'values': [v0, v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9],
                           'marker': {'colors': [
                                                 'rgb(0, 204, 0)',  # Green
                                                 'rgb(255, 255, 0)',  # Yellow
                                                 'rgb(118, 17, 195)',  # Purple
                                                 'rgb(0, 48, 240)'  # Blue
                                                 'rgb(240, 88, 0)'  # Orange
                                                 'rgb(215, 11, 11)'  # Red
                                                 'rgb(11, 133, 215)'  # Light Blue
                                                 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'  # Black
                                                 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                                                 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                                                ]
                                     },
                           'type': 'pie',
                           'name': "Gym grades",
                           'hoverinfo':'label+percent+name',
                           'textinfo':'none'
                      }
                      ],

             'layout': {'title': 'Grades in gym'}

             }

    url = py.plot(pie_chart, validate=False, filename='Gym Grades')
```

Problem: colors aren't changing ('marker' has no effect)

Question: is there a different way I'm supposed to modify the colors

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When you have a code example which isn't working for you, it is important to explain very clearly what the problem is -- what exactly is it doing right now, and what is it exactly that it should be doing. This is not clear from your question right now.

Comment: Problem: colors aren't changing ('marker' has no effect) - Question: is there a different way I'm supposed to modify the colors

Comment: Ok, you should edit that into the question then

Comment: Your example works for me. Here is the plot url: https://plot.ly/~christopherp/1131/grades-in-gym/. Is that different than what you get?

Comment: Hmm..the first 4 (v0-v3) seem to be the correct colors, but the rest are all wrong. For reference, the last 3 should be black. Perhaps there isn't a way yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plotly does pretty well with hiding your errors and auto completing the missing colors. There are few missing commas, below a working example of colored pie chart.

As Meglio offered, the `sort` attribute can be set to false, but this only changes the order of the legend and the chart. The colors are set by the ordering of the arrays.

```js
pie_chart = {
  'data': [{
    'labels': ['V0', 'V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4', 'V5', 'V6', 'V7', 'V8', 'V9'],
    'values': [55, 22, 31, 32, 33, 45, 44, 42, 12, 67],
    'marker': {
      'colors': [
        'rgb(0, 204, 0)',
        'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
        'rgb(118, 17, 195)',
        'rgb(0, 48, 240)',
        'rgb(240, 88, 0)',
        'rgb(215, 11, 11)',
        'rgb(11, 133, 215)',
        'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
        'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
      ]
    },
    'type': 'pie',
    'name': "Gym grades",
    'hoverinfo': 'label+percent+name',
    'sort': false,
  }],

  'layout': {
    'title': 'Grades in gym'
  }

}

Plotly.newPlot('plot', pie_chart.data, pie_chart.layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="plot"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that by default all the values v0, v1, ... are sorted descending, so that the biggest values come first. They are sorted **after** "applying" colors to them. So, value #4, which is Blue as by your colors definition, may come not 4th.

The solution would be to order your data manually and **turn auto-ordering off** with using [sort](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#pie-sort) attribute.